# Ubuntu quickly change package installation folder

Tags: ubuntu, package, canonical-quickly

I used "quickly package" to create the deb package. I have no idea how to change the installation location of my application from /usr to /opt with this resource. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
$quickly package --extra
```